# jquery menu issues in IE

Tags: jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/NYkdz/) is an example. The menu works fine everywhere I've tried except IE7&8.

In IE I can't highlight the sub-menu items and the animated height is wrong (its to short and not displaying all the items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cold use a slimest function to animate the menus like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("ul.menu li").hover(function() { 
        //$(this).find("ul:eq(0)").show('fast');
        //$(this).find("ul:eq(0)").slideDown('fast');
        $(this).find("ul:eq(0)").stop(false, true).animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 'fast'); 
    }, function() { 
        //$(this).find("ul:eq(0)").hide('fast'); 
        //$(this).find("ul:eq(0)").slideUp('fast');
        $(this).find("ul:eq(0)").stop(false, true).animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 'fast'); 
    }); 
});
```

And in your SobMenu class, change the CSS from this:

```
.SubMenu {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: #3d2f26;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}
```

To this:

```
.SubMenu {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: #3d2f26;
    top: 100%;
}
```

See if it helps.

About the highlight, IE8 and older only accept :hover pseudo-selector in A tag. To solve this issue, wrap the text in the LI elements in A tags and apply the paddings and other stylings to this.

Comment: You could instead add a time to the `show` and `hide` functions. If the animation you want is to slide up and down, you could use `slideUp` and `slideDown` functions or `animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 'fast')` to hide and `animate({height: 'show', opacity: 'show'}, 'fast');`. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFprf/4/). It has an example.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. A note on the css hacks on the example: css hacks aren't good, I've used it just for brevity. You have to put the properties in a separate file and use condicional comments to link the stylesheet. In this case, IE6 and 7 add spaces between the menu items if `display: block` is used.